error al correr una maquina virtual en vmware fusion
utilizo vmware fusion en Macos sonoma y me marca el siguiente error -Error de transporte (VMDB) -14: Pipe connection has been broken - ya intenté reiniciar la máquina virtual, pero no me permite hacer nada, ojalá alguien me pueda ayudar, pues soy nuevo usando esta aplicación gracias
